# Importing OSB Config Jar in Service Bus Console of Different Environment

Tags: service, osb, bus

I have created an OSB Project in Oracle Jdeveloper 12c.Based on the Oracle docs I created config jar for the same and imported in local weblogic server. It is working fine. But If I import the same config jar to a different Environment, I am getting **Invalid Config Jar** error in the SBConsole. Please suggest if we need to change anything in the Config Jar before importing it to a different environment/system ? Basically how to deploy service bus projects in different environments through service bus console ?

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue causing the above problem. I was using weblogic 12.2.1.2 version locally and the test environment weblogic version was 12.2.1.0. Because of the version mismatch the config jar created locally was rejected by the est environment.